# Symfony 2.6 get Service LoggedUser Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 must be an instance

Tags: symfony, logging, service, dependency-injection

I  want to implement the security.token_storage as a service to get the user that is logged in; so when the user writes a post or a comment the field "Author" is automatically set.

I cannot get it working:

Attempted to call method "get" on class "Blog\BlogBundle\Services\PostManager".

How can I implement it as a service and use it?

The UserManager (as a service):
    namespace Usuarios\UsersBundle\Services;

```
class UserManager

public function getloggedUser()
{
    $loggedUser = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    return $loggedUser;
}
```

The service.yml for the UserManager config:

```
services:
    user_manager:
        class: %user_manager.class%
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

The PostManager, that uses the getloggedUser function:
    namespace Blog\BlogBundle\Services;

```
class PostManager

private $em;
private $formFactory;
private $um;

/**
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param formFactoryInterface $formFactory
 * @param UserManager $um
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManager $um)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->um = $um;

public function createComment (Post $post, Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();

    $comment->setPost($post);

    //this is the line failing:
    $comment->setAuthorName($this->um->getloggedUser());

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(new CommentType(), $comment);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->em->persist($comment);
        $this->em->flush();

        return true;
    }

    return $form;
```

Note "user_manager" is defined as a service and is fully functional since other functions using it are working. Why cannot I call the UserManager service from the PostManager service? The error I get is:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Blog\BlogBundle\Services\PostManager::__construct() must be an instance of Usuarios\UsersBundle\Services\UserManager, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\eScribely2\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2535 and defined
```

Answer (score 0):

services do not have the get convenience method that controllers do.  You need to pass the container in as an argument when you build the service and store it as a member variable and then call you service.

```
$this->container->get('user_manager');
```

Optionally you can just pass in your user manger and not have to use the container at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However correcting that I got another error which is in the constructor, it must be an instance an I cannot tget it working. Thanks for yor time.

Comment: it's because you didn't pass in your user manager in your services arguments.